# Java Class Cast Exception when creating Generic Array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am trying to write a PriorityQueue which must be genericized to a Comparable. Here is the constructor:

```
public class DavidiArrayPriorityQueue <E extends Comparable<E>> implements PriorityQueue<E> {

    private E data[];
    private int numElements;

    //creates an empty priority queue with 10 spaces by default
    public DavidiArrayPriorityQueue(){

        data= (E[]) new Object[20];
        numElements=0;
    }
```

When I initialize it with

```
DavidiArrayPriorityQueue<Integer> test=new DavidiArrayPriorityQueue<Integer>();
```

It throws [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;

Comment: Indeed; an `Object` is not a `Comparable`.

Comment: Maybe you should use a List instead of an array?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Or, more to the point: an `Object[]` is not a `Comparable[]`.

Answer (score 4):

The element-type of an array is actually part of the array, known at runtime. So when you write `new Object[]`, you are creating an array with element-type `Object`, and even if your intent is that the elements of the array will all always have type (say) `Comparable`, you still can't cast it to `Comparable[]`.

In your case, you're casting it to `E[]`. Due to erasure, the cast can't be fully enforced at runtime, so it's downgraded to a cast to `Comparable[]`; so, technically speaking, you could trick the compiler into allowing this, by writing `(E[]) new Comparable[]`. But that's a bad idea, because then you have an array expression of type `E[]` whose element-type is not actually `E`. You've circumvented the type system, and this can cause confusing errors later on.

It's better to just have `data` be of type `Object[]` (or perhaps `Comparable<?>[]`), and perform the necessary casts to `E`. This will result in compiler warnings, because the compiler won't be able to check those casts, either, but at least you can verify that your code is correct and correctly preserves the type system (and then suppress the warnings, with a comment).

Comment: Casting `new Comparable<?>[]` to `E[]` should be fine as long as the array isn't exposed outside of the class (where it might be assigned to a reifiable type).

Comment: @PaulBellora, that situation arises in the classes of the `Collections` framework in the [`java.util`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html)

Comment: Like in [`Vector`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java). Here an `Object[]` is used for storage and for obtaining elements, type casting is used.

Comment: @ambigram_maker Understood. Yes that's perfectly fine too, except perhaps more unchecked warnings to suppress.